# I want to call several api and combine the response values of different object types

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, coroutine

I want to call several api and combine the response values of different object types.

```
    val itemList : MutableList<BaseItem>
    
    private fun fetchAllData() {
            viewModelScope.launch{
                val deferreds = listOf(
                        async { loadData1()},    
                        async { loadData2()}    
                ) 
                deferreds.awaitAll().forEach {
                    itemList.add(it)
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to get a return by combining datatype1 and datatype2 into BaseItem.

Unable to return the callback data from the repository.
I think there's a way to do it using live data. What should I do?

```
    fun loadData1(): ArrayList<DataType1> {
      repository.getData1(param, callback) {
         onSuccess(List<DataType1>) {
            return 
         }
      }
    }
    
    fun loadData2(): ArrayList<DataType2> {
      repository.getData1(param, callback) {
         onSuccess(List<DataType2>) {
            return
         }
      }
    }
```

I'll be waiting for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question's tags to include the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I would do is I would switch repository functions to be `suspend` functions and write the code in synchronized way:

```kotlin
val itemsLiveData = MutableLiveData<BaseItem>()
    
    private fun fetchAllData() = viewModelScope.launch{
        try {
            val itemList : MutableList<BaseItem>
            itemsList.addAll(repository.loadData1(param))
            itemsList.addAll(repository.loadData2(param))
            itemsLiveData.postValue(itemsList)
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            // do something with exception
        }
    }
```

And if you want to call several Rest API for example, I would go with Retrofit which has built-in support for suspend functions since ver. 2.6.0

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-260-2019-06-05

Comment: Repository does not return BaseItem. The repository returns objects of different types per api.

Comment: Then either DataType1 and DataType2 should inherit from BaseItem, or be mapped to another model which inherits from BaseItem or BaseItem can be even a `sealed class`